# How to redirect to a specific page after successful login using express and vue js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vuejs2

I am developing a simple CRUD application using MVEN stack. I have also added authentication feature using passportJs. But I am getting error in redirecting. I guess there is some mistake with the routing that I have used. I have shared my code below.

**authRoutes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var authRoutes = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

app = express();
// Require Item model in our routes module
var User = require('../models/User');
var Item = require('../models/Item');


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

// Serialize user in session
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser((username, done) => {
  const user = getUser(username);
  delete user.password;
  done(null, user);
});

authRoutes.route('/register').post(function (req, res) {
var user = new User(req.body);
      user.save()
    .then(user => {
    res.status(200).json({'user': 'user added successfully'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

authRoutes.route('/login').post( function(req, res){
  passport.authenticate('local',{
    failureRedirect: '/',
    successRedirect: '/display',
    failureFlash: true,
  });
});



authRoutes.route('/display').get(function (req, res) {
  Item.find(function (err, items){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(items);
    }
  });
});


module.exports = authRoutes
```

login.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Register User</h1>
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="registerUser">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="user.email">
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" v-model="user.password">
            </div>
            <button>Register</button>
            </form>
            <p v-if="isRegistered">Thanks for registering.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="loginUser">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="loginData.email">
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" v-model="loginData.password">
            </div>
            <button>Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        data (){
            return{
                user:{},
                isRegistered: false,
                loginData:{}
            };
        },
        methods: {
            registerUser(){
                let uri = 'http://localhost:4000/auths/register';
              this.axios.post(uri, this.user).then((response) => {
                this.isRegistered = true;
                this.user = {};
              })
              .catch((err) => console.log(err));
            },

            loginUser(){
                let uri = 'http://localhost:4000/auths/login';
                debugger;
                this.axios.post(uri, this.loginData).then((response) => {
                    this.$router.push({name:'DisplayItem'});
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);

                    this.$router.push({name:'Register'});
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The issue is, it is not redirecting to /display when username and password are correct. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumble upon this...

In this part you're catching the error of axios, which has to be returned by the server (eg. not 200, not redirect, if I am not wrong)

```
loginUser(){
  let uri = 'http://localhost:4000/auths/login';
  debugger;
  this.axios.post(uri, this.loginData).then((response) => {
    this.$router.push({name:'DisplayItem'});
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.$router.push({name:'Register'});
  });
}
```

However, in the server you're not doing so, since passport have no idea what to do after lookup the user (as defined in the local strategy).

```
authRoutes.route('/login').post( function(req, res){
  passport.authenticate('local',{
    failureRedirect: '/',
    successRedirect: '/display',
    failureFlash: true,
  });
});
```

You might achieve what you're trying to do with something slightly different

```
passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
  }

  // if no user we assume something went wrong
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({msg: 'Invalid mail or password'})
  }

  // call method injected by passport into express request object,
  // passing the user returned by passport strategy

  req.logIn(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
    }
    console.log("Login Exitoso")
    return res.status(200).json({msg:'Login succesfully'})
  })
})(req, res, next)
```

You might also have redirect issues if you're using both server for front-end development (like webpack dev server) and express (for api routing), since emitting redirect responses from express would result in a CORS problem on front-end dev server.

Just in case :)